# How to properly display number of 75 cent, 30 cent coins, and 1 cent coins?

Tags: java

I have an assignment in which I have to create a method where I have to receive money from a customer and give them change back depending on the price. The needed amounts of money are `$130`, `$55`, `$25`, `$5`, `$1`, `$0.75`, `$0.30`, and `$0.01`.

The frustrating situation currently is that it fails to properly display the number of coins, but succeeds in the number of dollars. For example, if an item costs `$0.94` and someone gave me `$218`, the change should be 1 of each amount (1x `$130`, 1x `$55`, 1x `$25`, 1x `$5`, and etc..). But whenever I ask for the values, I get two `$1`, and zero `$0.75` and `$0.30`, and six `$0.01` coins.

```
public class change {
    static int ot;
    static int numot;
    static int ff;
    static int numff;
    static int tf;
    static int numtf;
    static int f;
    static int numf;
    static int o;
    static int numo;
    static int scc;
    static double numscc;       
    static int tcc;
    static double numtcc;
    static int occ;
    static double numocc;

    public static double result(double salesTotal, double customerPayment){
        System.out.println("How much does it cost?");
        double price=IO.readDouble();
        salesTotal=price;
        System.out.println("How much do you have?");
        double money=IO.readDouble();
        customerPayment=money;
        double change=money-price;

        if (change>=0.01&&change/130>=1){
            numot= (int) change/130;
            change= change%130;
            numff= (int) change/55;
            change= change%55;
            numtf= (int) change/25;
            change= change%25;
            numf= (int) change/5;
            change= change%5;
            numo= (int) change/1;
            change= change%1;
            numscc=  change/0.75;
            change= change%0.75;
            numtcc=  change/0.30;
            change= change%0.30;
            numocc=  change/0.01;
            change= change%0.01;                    
        }
        else if (change>=0.01&&change<130&&change/55>=1){
            numff= (int) change/55;
            change= change%55;
            numtf= (int) change/25;
            change= change%25;
            numf= (int) change/5;
            change= change%5;
            numo= (int) change/1;
            change= change%1;
            numscc=  change/0.75;
            change= change%0.75;
            numtcc=  change/0.30;
            change= change%0.30;
            numocc=  change/0.01;
            change= change%0.01;
        }
        else if (change>=0.01&&change<55&&change/25>=1){
            numtf= (int) change/25;
            change= change%25;
            numf= (int) change/5;
            change= change%5;
            numo= (int) change/1;
            change= change%1;
            numscc=  change/0.75;
            change= change%0.75;
            numtcc=  change/0.30;
            change= change%0.30;
            numocc=  change/0.01;
            change= change%0.01;
        }   
        else if (change>=0.01&&change<25&&change/5>=1){
            numf= (int) change/5;
            change= change%5;
            numo= (int) change/1;
            change= change%1;
            numscc=  change/0.75;
            change= change%0.75;
            numtcc=  change/0.30;
            change= change%0.30;
            numocc=  change/0.01;
            change= change%0.01;
        }
        return numff;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        double a= result(2,5);
        IO.outputStringAnswer(numot + " $130 bills");
        IO.outputStringAnswer(numff + " $55 bills");
        IO.outputStringAnswer(numtf + " $25 bills");
        IO.outputStringAnswer(numf + " $5 bills");
        IO.outputStringAnswer(numo + " $1 bills");
        IO.outputStringAnswer((int) numscc + " $0.75 coin");
        IO.outputStringAnswer((int) numtcc + " $0.30 coin");
        IO.outputStringAnswer((int) numocc + " $0.01 coin");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm (really) wondering is there a 30 cents coin?

Comment: Nope, not at all. It's just what they want us to do for the assignment

Answer (score 0):

I dummed your program down a little for debugging, but it works like a charm:

```
    public class change {

    static int ot, numot, ff, numff, tf, numtf, f, numf, o, numo, scc, nuscc, tcc, utcc, occ;
    static double numscc, numtcc, numocc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double change = 218 - 0.94;

        if (change >= 0.01 && change / 130 >= 1) {
            numot = (int) change / 130;
            change %= 130;
            numff = (int) change / 55;
            change %= 55;
            numtf = (int) change / 25;
            change %= 25;
            numf = (int) change / 5;
            change %= 5;
            numo = (int) change / 1;
            change %= 1;
            numscc = change / 0.75;
            change %= 0.75;
            numtcc = change / 0.30;
            change %= 0.30;
            numocc = change / 0.01;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Other value");
        }

        System.out.println(numot + " $130 bills");
        System.out.println(numff + " $55 bills");
        System.out.println(numtf + " $25 bills");
        System.out.println(numf + " $5 bills");
        System.out.println(numo + " $1 bills");
        System.out.println((int) numscc + " $0.75 coin");
        System.out.println((int) numtcc + " $0.30 coin");
        System.out.println((int) numocc + " $0.01 coin");
    }

}
```

So if you have a problem it I suggest it is because of some kind of IO error, defenitly not because of your logic.

Comment: Thanks but i apologize for not being more specific. 218- 0.94 was just an example. it needs to work for any possible scenario